# Listings, tables and figures in one Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

Because I am a completely newbie I do not know to solve the above described problem and I also did not found anything at researching the internet.

I like to let it look like the following example:

Table of Figures
- Fig.1 1 
- Fig.2.3
- Listing 1 4
- Fig.3....4
- Listing 2 5
- Listing 3 6
- Table 1 6

The second number stays for the pagenumber.

Thank your for helping!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. This is possible, but looks extraordinary ugly and is confusing readers to find the proper information.

Comment: A possible way is to change `\tl@lof` and `\tl@lot` etc. to be `\tl@toc` as is done effectively in my answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/421909/31729

Comment: In my second comment I meant `\tf@lof` etc. not `\tl@lof`, I did not remember correctly!

Comment: Is that the same question as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/467027/35864? If so, you may want to mark your earlier question as a duplicate of this one. Note that it would have been nicer to edit your other earlier question instead of just asking a new one. It would also have been great if you had followed the advice in the comments and provided a short example document (an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)) that people can use to start from and test their solutions.

Answer (score 5):

**Disclaimer:** I don't recommend merging non - figure - like entries such as tables or listings in a List of Figures at all...

One way is to change the file handles `\tf@lot` and `\tf@lol` that are used to write to the relevant `.lot` and `.lof` files in order to be equal as `\tf@lof`, such that any write attempt to `.lot` and `.lol` will end up in `.lof`.

The following code does exactly this and uses `\string` in order to prevent premature expansion of `\let\tf@lot\tf@lof` etc.

Since `@` is occuring in macro names, `\makeatletter...\makeatother` is necessary.

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \string\let\string\tf@lot\string\tf@lof^^J%
    \string\let\string\tf@lol\string\tf@lof
  }
}
\makeatother
```

The loaded packages are just for quicker generation of content, but not really necessary, apart from `listings` (thanks to moewe for pointing out!), but `caption` and `xpatch` simplify the whole issue a lot.

Since `\captionsetup[lstlisting]{listformat=simple}` does not work, I patched `\lst@MakeCaption` in order to provide for the correct prefix in the List of Figures.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{tocloft}


\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
% Must be done before caption packages changes \lst@MakeCaption
\xpatchcmd{\lst@MakeCaption}{%
  \addcontentsline{lol}{lstlisting}%
  {\protect\numberline{\thelstlisting}\lst@@caption}%
}{%
  \addcontentsline{lol}{lstlisting}%
  {\protect\numberline{\p@lstlisting\ \thelstlisting}\lst@@caption}%
}{\typeout{Foo}}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{caption}


\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
  \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Table of Figures}% Better: \addtocaptions{english}{\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Table of Figures}} if babel is loaded
  \addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{20pt}
  \addtolength{\cfttabnumwidth}{20pt}
  % Add the prefixes
  \renewcommand{\p@table}{Tab.}
  \renewcommand{\p@figure}{Fig.}
  \renewcommand{\p@lstlisting}{\lstlistingname}% 
  \let\l@lstlisting\l@figure%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \string\let\string\tf@lot\string\tf@lof^^J%
    \string\let\string\tf@lol\string\tf@lof
  }
}
\makeatother


\captionsetup[figure]{listformat=simple}
\captionsetup[table]{listformat=simple}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\clearpage

\foreach \x in {1,...,5} {%
\section{Foo  section \x}
\blindtext


\begin{figure}
\caption{A foo figure with number \x }
\end{figure}


\begin{table}
\caption{A foo table with number \x }
\end{table}
}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,caption={Foo listing One}]

  printf("Hello World\n");
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: Just to mention that all the loaded packages (in particular `pgffor`) are just for the MWE and not needed for the core of the solution. And one should definitely change the heading of the LOF and the layout to make sure that the numbers also get their respective 'type prefix'.

Comment: @moewe: Thanks for suggestion, I was not finished yet. I will add the changes later on...

Comment: I noticed that you added more explanatory text while I was writing the comment or shortly after ... but I had already typed so much so I thought I might as well send it off.

Comment: @moewe: I added the necessary prefixes to the LOF entries... During my hiatus I seem to have forgotten some TeX details, so it took me much longer than initially planned

Answer (score 1):

In a simple way, I think `\addcontentsline` would do the trick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Lipsum 1 -- 15}
\lipsum[1-12]

This is a line. \textbf{It will be added to the ToC.}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{A custom line or something you want}
% maybe Figure 1.2 or something
\lipsum[13-16]
\section{Another lipsum}
\subsection{Checking}
\lipsum[17-19]
\subsection{Another checking sub-section}
\lipsum[20-30]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**However I do NOT recommend doing like this, because it will be extremely ugly IMHO!**

Comment: I assume (the question is a bit thin on details) that the OP wants to use the usual `\caption` command within each floating environment they want to add to the 'unified LoF', so I'm not sure if `\addcontentsline` is enough. But I'm just speculating and extrapolating based on this question and the earlier https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/467027/35864.

Comment: I like to combine the lists as I said. I dont know how to write give it more details, because this is all. 

Comment: @MrXeth I don't really understand what you mean. Could you rephrase it?