# Combine Table of Content, Figures and Tables

Tags: table-of-contents

I would like a way to combine the Table of Content, Table of Figures and, Table of Tables into the same list.
Currently I have

```
\tableofcontents
\renewcommand\listtablename{Case Tables}
\listoftables
\listoffigures
```

For example:

```
1 Section
   2. Subsection
      Figure
      Figure
2. Section
   1. Subsection
      Table 
      Table
   2. Subsection
      Figure
```

Comment: The existing \caption is not set up for this.  You could write your own \caption macro to add figures and tables to the `toc` file, or simply append \addcontentsline after each \caption.

Comment: See a possible solution here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/467190/31729 ... the change to have be done is switching from `tf@lol` to `tf@lof` etc.

Comment: Please note that readers do usually not suspect `table` or `figure` captions in the regular ToC -- if your document has a lot of tables or figures, the ToC might get crowded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to force LaTeX not writing to the `.lof` and `.lot` files any longer but to change the file handles for both to `.toc` files.

This is done by

```
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \string\let\string\tf@lot\string\tf@toc^^J%
    \string\let\string\tf@lof\string\tf@toc
  }
```

right at the start of the document.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{caption}


\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
  \addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{25pt}
  \addtolength{\cfttabnumwidth}{25pt}
  % Add the prefixes
  \renewcommand{\p@table}{Table}
  \renewcommand{\p@figure}{Figure}
  % Change the file handle from lot to toc and from lof to toc
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \string\let\string\tf@lot\string\tf@toc^^J%
    \string\let\string\tf@lof\string\tf@toc
  }
}
\makeatother


\captionsetup[figure]{listformat=simple}
\captionsetup[table]{listformat=simple}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\cleardoublepage

\foreach \x in {1,...,5} {%
\section{Foo  section \x}

\blindtext

\subsection{Foo subsection 1}
\blindtext

\begin{figure}[htp]
\caption{A foo figure with number \x }
\end{figure}

\subsubsection{Foo subsubsection 2}

\begin{table}[htp]
\caption{A foo table with number \x }
\end{table}
}



\end{document}
```