# Merge toc and new float of float package, "list of everything"

Tags: floats, koma-script

Although everyone considers this worst practice I'm working on merging all lists in my document into one (toc, lot and lof). I got the easiest way to do this from [Combine Table of Content, Figures and Tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473989/combine-table-of-content-figures-and-tables):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{caption, float, hyperref}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
  \immediate\write\@auxout{
     \string\let\string\tf@lof\string\tf@toc
     % ...
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{One}
\begin{figure}[H]
  figure \caption{Foo figure}\label{fig:foo}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Which creates something along those lines:
[image: table of contents with list of tables and figures included]

*Although it seems crowded at first glance, I like how it turned out*.

**My problem is that I want to define a new float environment** `iEQ` **using the** `float` **package:**

```
\newfloat{iEQ}{H}{toc}
```

This float environment should also be listed in the table of contents, so I used `toc` as the extension, but this fails:

```
test.toc | Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

at this line:

```
\contentsline {iEQ}{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces test\relax }}{3}{iEQ.1}%
```

**How do I make the** `float` **package's** `\newfloat` **environments appear in the table of contents?**

Answer (score 3):

With a KOMA-Script class use `\DeclareNewTOC` (provided by KOMA-Script package `tocbasic`) to define a new TOC:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{float}% only used for the H-position
\usepackage{scrhack}% because of package float together a KOMA-Script class
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareNewTOC[
  counterwithin=chapter,
  float,
  floattype=4,
  floatpos=H
]{iEQ}

\makeatletter
  \renewcommand*{\l@iEQ}{\l@figure}
  \renewcommand*{\ext@iEQ}{toc}
  \renewcommand*{\ext@figure}{toc}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents\KOMAScriptVersion
\chapter{One}
\begin{figure}[H]
  figure \caption{Foo figure}\label{fig:foo}
\end{figure}
\begin{iEQ}
  iEQ \caption{Bar iEQ}\label{iEQ:bar}
\end{iEQ}
\end{document}
```

or with the prerelease of KOMA-Script version 3.28 (can be installed from the [KOMA-Script website](https://komascript.de/node/1801)):

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}[2019/12/06]
\usepackage{float}% only used for the H-position
\usepackage{scrhack}% because of package float together a KOMA-Script class
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareNewTOC[
  counterwithin=chapter,
  float,
  floattype=4,
  floatpos=H,
  tocentrylevel:=figure,
  tocentryindent:=figure,
  tocentrynumwidth:=figure
]{iEQ}

\makeatletter
  \renewcommand*{\ext@iEQ}{toc}
  \renewcommand*{\ext@figure}{toc}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents\KOMAScriptVersion
\chapter{One}
\begin{figure}[H]
  figure \caption{Foo figure}\label{fig:foo}
\end{figure}
\begin{iEQ}
  iEQ \caption{Bar iEQ}\label{iEQ:bar}
\end{iEQ}
\end{document}
```

Or without `\DeclareNewTOC`:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{float}% only used for the H-position
\usepackage{scrhack}% because of package float together a KOMA-Script class
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
  \newenvironment{iEQ}%
    {\@float{iEQ}}
    {\end@float}
  \newcommand*{\fps@iEQ}{H}
  \newcommand*{\ftype@iEQ}{4}
  \newcounter{iEQ}
  \counterwithin{iEQ}{chapter}
  \newcommand*{\iEQformat}{IEQ~\theiEQ\autodot}
  \newcommand*{\l@iEQ}{\l@figure}
  \newcommand*{\ext@iEQ}{toc}
  \renewcommand*{\ext@figure}{toc}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents%\KOMAScriptVersion
\chapter{One}
\begin{figure}[H]
  figure \caption{Foo figure}\label{fig:foo}
\end{figure}
\begin{iEQ}
  iEQ \caption{Bar iEQ}\label{iEQ:bar}
\end{iEQ}
\end{document}
```

---

If you really want to use `\newfloat`:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrhack}% because of package float together a KOMA-Script class
\usepackage{caption, float, hyperref}
\newfloat{iEQ}{H}{iEQ}[chapter]
\makeatletter
  \AtBeginDocument{
    \immediate\write\@auxout{
       \string\let\string\tf@lof\string\tf@toc
       \string\let\string\tf@iEQ\string\tf@toc
       % ...
  }}
  \newcommand{\l@iEQ}{\l@figure}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listof{iEQ}{Test}
\chapter{One}
\begin{figure}[H]
  figure \caption{Foo figure}\label{fig:foo}
\end{figure}
\begin{iEQ}
  iEQ \caption{Bar iEQ}\label{iEQ:bar}
\end{iEQ}
\end{document}
```